# How to display two string in to listview in android

Tags: android, string, listview

I have this type of two String. Now  i want to display these two string in to listview.

> String timeString= 0:10, 0:50, 1:05, 0:29
>
> String pointString =    75, 50, 150, 95

My question is, how to display this two string just like this type of listview.

> Time........ Point
>
> 0:10 ......        75
>
> 0:50 .....        50
>
> 1:05.....         150
>
> 0:29......         95

I have one **score_format.xml** and **main.xml** file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so obvious . use customAdapter pass both arrays through its constructor . now in getView set values to both the views contains inside inflated view . for god sake dont ask for code , because 100's of similar questions available here .